# EpubCheck troubleshooting; declaration errors

Tags: epub

I need some extra pairs of more experienced eyes on these declaration warnings:

[image: warning]

and this code:

[image: code]

As you can see; despite what the declaration warnings may say, I indeed have declared the file in the OPF. The OPF is in its standard location inside the OEBPS folder. I have spent a good few hours trying to find what is wrong, and I still don't see why epubcheck isn't seeing the declaration.

**Things that I've checked:**
• The declaration is between the `<manifest></manifest>` tags.
• The path is correct. (Unless I'm missing something)
• I've tried to make sure that the mimetype file comes first in the zip.

Since I'm very new to creating epubs, I don't know if I'm missing something else entirely, like, there's something wrong with the code before the css declarations. Would you have any suggestions as to what I could check?

Comment: That looks right, but we'd probably need to see the complete set of errors/warnings and complete OPF file. If there was an earlier error in the OPF, epubcheck tends to bail on processing it, and then skips all further declarations, leading to a false negative like this. But it's also possible that something else is wrong.

Answer (score 1):

It turns out, there was a discrepancy between the spelling of the `iexcercises` folder and the declared `iexercises` folder. There was no 'C'.

Also, I found a very helpful comment on a forum site while I was troubleshooting the epub; it describes how to save the epubcheck errors and warnings log into a text file for easier browsing.

[Source](https://code.google.com/p/epubcheck/wiki/Running)

> Comment by bernieh2...@gmail.com, Nov 6, 2011 || My five cents for
>   non-techies...
>
> For using epubcheck on a Windows PC, do the following:
>
> (1) Download and unzip the latest epubcheck version wherever you
>   please on your computer (That is, rename the unzipped folder as you
>   like and put it on whatever directory you may deem it fit). For the
>   sake of this explanation, let's rename such unzipped folder as
>   "my_epubcheck" (w/o the "" characters).
>
> (2) Open any ASCII text editor of your choice (e.g. notepad) and type
>   the following:
>
> java -jar epubcheck-1.2.jar file.epub> report.txt 2>&1
>
> pause
>
> (3) Save this as an ASCII text file (name it, let's say,
>   "validate.bat" -- w/o the "" characters) on your my_epubcheck folder.
>   The only important thing is that the extension MUST be .bat
>
> (4) To check any epub file, do the following:
>
> - Copy the file you intend to check to your my_epubcheck folder. Rename it as "file.epub" (w/o the "" characters).
> - Double-click on the validate.bat icon in your my_epubcheck folder.
> - A new (system) window will appear on your screen, epubcheck will start working and then pause with the message "press any key to
>     continue..."
> - Press any key.
> - Examine the contents of your my_epubcheck folder. You'll find a file named report.txt.
> - Double-click on the report.txt icon to see the results of your test.
>
> IMPORTANT: Should you use a different epubcheck version, replace
>   epubcheck-1.2.jar on the validate.bat file with the exact name of the
>   .jar file you're using (find the name in your my_epubcheck folder).
>
> Hope this helps,
>
> Bernieh.

Again, I hope this helps someone!

Comment: Glad you got it squared away! You might check out http://ebooks.stackexchange.com/ for help with this sort of thing in the future, fyi.